# disabling a checkbox using prettycheckable

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a form that when a checkbox is checked then it disables the checkbox so they cannot uncheck it. This is what the client wants and is applicable for this particular situation. If I were in any other situation this would be bad usability.

I'm having a bit of trouble making this work though. With prettycheckable it has `disableInput();` to help and it does work, but not exactly how I need it to.

I've tried a few things like this

```
if ($('a').hasClass('.checked')) {
         FormHelper.disableInput();
       }
```

where I'm checking to see if there is a tag that prettycheckable adds the checked class to. If it does then I was trying to disable that checkbox.

I know I am doing something silly, any help would be appreciated!

The html looks like this

```
<p class="pull-right check"><input type="checkbox" class="checkIt" name="" value="" /><span>Read</span></p>
```

Comment: Syntax looks fine, when are you running this piece of code?

Comment: In my main jQuery file it runs right after the prettycheckable is enabled. There is really no other place to put it.

Comment: *"I'm working on a form that when a checkbox is checked then it disables the checkbox so they cannot uncheck it."* - sounds like horrible usability.

Comment: Well, on page load, are any of the checkboxes checked?

Comment: And, @ThiefMaster -  You read my mind...accidental click? Aaaand page reload :)

Comment: the syntax is wrong! you don't need `.` to check the class existence try `hasClass('checked')`

Comment: @ThiefMaster I know it's awful usability, but thats what the client wants. I cant change her mind.

Comment: @MaveRick Even without the . it still wont work. That was what I initially tried.

Comment: ok can you give me an html example so i can give you an exact jquery code

Comment: @MaveRick I added the html above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('input.checkIt').prettyCheckable();
    $('input.checkIt').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
           $(this).attr('disabled','disabled').parent().addClass('disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not going to work for this situation because I am using a plugin called prettycheckable. The actual html changes as soon as you click on it with images. That was why I was trying to use their build in method of disableInput(); when the class is on the a tag.

Comment: then you can replace `.attr('disabled','disabled');` with `.disableInput();`

i just added `$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');` as an example of what you can do in this statement

Comment: Even changing that will not work, the actual input goes away as soon as the plug in kicks in and replaces it with images. That is why I put the name of the actual plugin in the name if the title.

Comment: can you give me a link for the jquery plugin `FormHelper` that you are using with your forms?

Comment: this is the prettycheckable http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/ the formHelper comes from Larvel's form helpers.

Comment: also the change will not work because what if I have a class that is checked coming back from the database. I do not want them to be able to change it once it is checked and this resets everything on refresh because of that change.

Comment: Edited the answer can you check the new code pleas,
and if you have checked input you can disable it by adding `disabled="disabled"` to the input property

Comment: The only issue would be the change. What if the checkbox comes in from the database already checked, I don't want them to be able to uncheck it.

Comment: then add to the input tag `checked disabled` and the input will be checked & disabled

Comment: Add it to it in the database? I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: you are saying what if the `<input>` was checked, that means this check box is already checked as it came from the database, then your php file should look like `echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkIt" name="" value="" />';`
in that case all you have to do is to print the input tag as disabled check box to be 
`echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkIt" name="" value="" checked disabled />';`

Comment: Not exactly right, I ended up having to throw in if statements to check to see if the status was read and then  not echoing, but amending the input.

Comment: i can help you more if you gave me the php line echoing your input to understand what you mean exactly and help you achieve your idea

Comment: Thank you, I already figured it out by throwing in some if statements in the views...without echoing anything out. I'm in a mvc framework larvel so things are a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.checkIt').prettyCheckable('enable');`

and

`$('.checkIt').prettyCheckable('disable');`

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
$(function(){
$('input.checkIt').prettyCheckable();
$('input.checkIt').change(function(){
    if(//something){
      $(this).attr('disabled',true).parent().prettyCheckable('disable');
    }else{
      $(this).attr('disabled',true).parent().prettyCheckable('enable');
    }
});
```